# having shadow DOM children inside shadow DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I am trying to see if i can build a site mostly out of shadow DOM elements everything was working good untill i tried to put a shadow DOM element inside another shadow DOM element

**Like this**

```html
<body>
    <nik-header background="#16a085" title="Custom HTML Components" color="#1c2127"></nik-header>
    <nik-content background="#1c2127">
        <button>nerd</button>
        <nik-card title="nik"></nik-card>
    </nik-content>
</body>
```

and my component code looks like this

```js
//components.js

class nikHeader extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
        var title = this.getAttribute('title');
        var backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('background');
        var textColor = this.getAttribute('color');
        if(backgroundColor == null){
            backgroundColor = "white"
        }if(textColor == null){
            textColor == "black"
        }
        this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this._root.innerHTML = `
        <div class="shadow-nik-header">
            <center><h1>${title}</h1><center>
        </div>

        <style>

            .shadow-nik-header{
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                height:80px;
                background:${backgroundColor};
                font-family:helvetica;
                color:${textColor}
            }
        </style>

        `;
    }
}
class nikContent extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        var backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('background');
        var textColor = this.getAttribute('color');
        if(backgroundColor == null){
            backgroundColor = "white"
        }if(textColor == null){
            textColor == "black"
        }
        this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this._root.innerHTML = `
        <div class="shadow-nik-content">

        </div>

        <style>

            .shadow-nik-content{
                position:absolute;
                top:80px;
                right:0px;
                left:0px;
                bottom:0px;
                background:${backgroundColor};
                color:${textColor};
            }
        </style>

        `;
    }
}
class nikCard extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        var backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('background');
        var textColor = this.getAttribute('color');
        var title = this.getAttribute('title');
        var body = this.getAttribute('body');
        var footer = this.getAttribute('footer')
        if(backgroundColor == null){
            backgroundColor = "white"
        }if(textColor == null){
            textColor == "black"
        }
        this._root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this._root.innerHTML = `
        <div class="shadow-nik-card">
        <div class="shadow-nik-card-title">${title}</div>
        <div class="shadow-nik-card-body">${body}</div>
        <div class="shadow-nik-card-footer">${footer}</div>
        </div>

        <style>

            .shadow-nik-card{
                position:absolute;
                background:blue;
            }
        </style>

        `;
    }
}


window.customElements.define('nik-card', nikCard);
window.customElements.define('nik-content', nikContent);
window.customElements.define('nik-header', nikHeader);
```

the button I put up there in the `<nik-content></nik-content>` tag doesn't display inside the bounds of the element it's just at the top nothing is influencing it I also noticed that the actual element doesn't have any size or position unless I inspect and scroll down to the shadow element part of google chrome
is it possible to have shadow DOM children inside a shadow DOM parent? or can i only put them in regular elements?

Comment: did you try to add `display:inline-block`in the style definitions?

Comment: yeah it is still the same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use a `<slot>` element in the Shadow DOM HTML definition of the container `<nik-content>`. As a consequence, nothing is inserted inside it. The Shadow DOM hides the light DOM.

```
this._root.innerHTML = `
    <div class="shadow-nik-content">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    ...
  `;
```